# How to wrap node.js function to access them in organized way

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

So I come to this, I want to write into a DB and do other operations to work with my program logic, this is the guide that I'm following [Node.js Class Creation](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Node.js_Tutorial/0205__Node.js_Class_Creation.htm):

```js
//## This is my mysql_test.js file
function MySQL(){
var mysql = require('mysql'); 

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    //data omitted
});


function AppendRecordset (req, res){
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");      
      con.query(req, function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
      });
    });    
}

function UpdateRecordset (req, res) {
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;      
      con.query(req, function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
      });
    });    
}

function DeleteRecordset (req, res){
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;      
      con.query(req, function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Number of records deleted: " + result.affectedRows);
      });
    });    
}

function GetRecordset (req, res) {
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      con.query(req, function (err, res, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
      });
    });
}
}
```

I then have in a separate file(s) my app logic, and want to use what of the above as an object/class so I wrote this accordingly to that guide:

```
//##this is inside my main app file
//declare the sql processor
require('./mysql_test.js');
var DB = MySQL();
DB.AppendRecordset(sql_string, res);  //sql_string contains a valid SQL statement
```

But when I try to acces it using `` I get this error message: `ReferenceError: MySQL is not defined` what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these functions handle your routes, so I didn't change them. Because I don't know how your router is desined.

Create a file `dbHangler.js` and write this single function:

```
const mysql = require('mysql'); 

let con;

exports.execQuery = (query) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!con) {
      con = mysql.createConnection({
        //data omitted
      });
    }
    con.connect(function(err) {
        if(err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        else {
          console.log("Connected!");
          con.query(query, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            }
            else {
              resolve(res);
            }
          });
        }
      });    
  });
};
```

In your `dedicated.js` file, now you can write:

```
const dbObject = require('path/to/dbHandler');

function AppendRecordset (req, res){
    dbObject.execQuery(req)
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle error
      });
}

function AppendRecordset (req, res){
    dbObject.execQuery(req)
      .then(result => {
        console.log("Number of records deleted: " + result.affectedRows);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle error
      });
}

function AppendRecordset (req, res){
    dbObject.execQuery(req)
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle error
      });
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I hope this one helps you.

`DbHandler.js`

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

class DbHandler {
  constructor(config) {
    let self = this;
    self.dbConfig = config;
    self.connection = mysql.createConnection({
      //data omitted
    });
  }

  queryExecuter(query) {
    let self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      self.connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        else {
          console.log("Connected!");
          self.connection.query(query, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            }
            else {
              resolve(res);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  AppendRecordset(query) {
    let self = this;
    return self.queryExecuter(query)
      .then(result => {
        console.log("1 record inserted");
        return result;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle error
        throw error;
      });
  }

  UpdateRecordset(query) {
    let self = this;
    return self.queryExecuter(query)
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
        return result;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle error
        throw error;
      });
  }

  // and other functions
}

module.exports = DbHandler;
```

And use it like below:

```
let DB = require('/path/to/DbHandler');

let myDb = new DB(/* db config */);

db.UpdateRecordset('your query')
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: I rephrased my question to make it more clear, Im following an example.

Comment: I see I wanted to drop that callback but I understand that node.js is just based on that flow, and rsults are only accessible within the callback function, so differently than for example C# where it is a sync by default, you cannot call a function and have the execution stop until you have the returned value.